# Jest : Mock import of JSON file

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I am currently testing one of my React component like this:

```js
it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<Scene {...props} />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

My component `Scene` imports a `setting.json` file. I have that file on my local instance, but I do not push it on my CI instance. So when it tries to import it, the file is not found.

Is there a way to mock this file in my test ?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can either use [`moduleNameMapper`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-object-string-string) in your jest settings to point the import to an mocked json file.

```
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "setting.json": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/setting.json"
  }
}
```

Or you can use [`jest.mock`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/jest-object.html#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) inside your test to mock the file directly, note that you have to add the `{ virtual: true }` parameter.

```
jest.mock('path/to/setting.json', ()=>({
  settings: 'someSetting'
}), { virtual: true })
```

Comment: I tried the jest.mock approach and I am getting the following error `Cannot find module 'path/to/setting.json' from 'get.test.js'`

Comment: Please note that the path is relative to the test file.

Comment: I wanted to mock a "virtual" file, who doesn't really exist.
To do so, the option `{ virtual: true}` is needed. Example : `jest.mock('path/to/file, () => ({ foo: 'bar'}), { virtual: true })`. Thanks @andreas-köberle

Comment: Updated the answer to your findings

Comment: In jest 22, you do not need to use `{virtual: true}`. You will have problems with relative file imports.

Comment: I got this work so that there's one shared mock for all tests in test file. But how could I config a different mock for each test case in test file?

Answer (score 5):

For those looking to mock JSON in the form of an `Array`, just return an array from the callback.

```
jest.mock('./data.json', () => ([1, 2, 3]));
```

You can return other valid JSON types as well: `Object`, `String`, `Number`, `Boolean`, or `Null`.